# What would be an alternative for sum(distinct)?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which returns sum() of columns using multiple joins. The problem is that the values get multiplied with each join.

Sample code:

```
select c.Categories, sum(os.OpeningStock), sum(cs.[ClosingStock]) 
from #categories c 
join #openingstocks os on c.Categories = os.Categories
join #closingstocks cs on c.categories=cs.Categories
group by rollup(c.Categories)
```

Values get multiplied twice here since I'm using two joins.

I'm using sum(distinct) and it is presenting the correct answer but is there an another solution for it?

Comment: Without knowing more of your data model, it's hard  for us to give you an answer. What exactly are you summing up, and why would a join duplicate that sum?

Comment: Using `sum(distict col)` is definite wrong here - if, by chance, a column has two equal values, you'd only some one of them.

Comment: @SchmitzIT - they will get duplicates assuming that either #openingstocks or #closingstocks or both has multiple rows for a category. As the rows will be multiplied out by the join.

Comment: If they have multiple rows, surely there will be multiple values. How do you decide which is the correct single value? Something is very wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUM(DISTINCT)` will return the wrong results if any rows happen to have the same opening or closing stock

You can use

```
WITH os
     AS (SELECT Categories,
                SUM(os.OpeningStock) AS OpeningStock
         FROM   #openingstocks
         GROUP  BY Categories),
     cs
     AS (SELECT Categories,
                SUM(os.[ClosingStock]) AS [ClosingStock]
         FROM   #closingstocks
         GROUP  BY Categories)
SELECT c.Categories,
       SUM(os.OpeningStock),
       SUM(cs.[ClosingStock])
FROM   #categories c
       JOIN os
         ON c.Categories = os.Categories
       JOIN cs
         ON c.categories = cs.Categories
GROUP  BY rollup( c.Categories )
```